# Can the Fey Wanderer Ranger be targeted by a creature affected by its Misty Presence?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, unearthed-arcana, targeting

Wizards of the Coast recently (in February 2020) released a new set of subclasses for playtesting in [Unearthed Arcana: Subclasses, Part 3](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020-Subclasses03_0224.pdf).

Described in this document is the Fey Wanderer ranger's 15th-level [Misty Presence](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020-Subclasses03_0224.pdf#page=6) feature, which states the following (abridged for brevity):

> You can magically remove yourself from one creature's perception: you gain a bonus action that you can use to force [a creature] to make a Wisdom saving throw [...]. On a failed save, the target can't see or hear you for 24 hours.

If the creature cannot see or hear the Fey Wanderer Ranger (and, indeed, if they are completely "removed from the target's senses"), then can they target or attack the Ranger at all? This, of course, is assuming that the target has the standard set of senses.

The document omits any mention of the *Invisible*, *Blinded*, *Deafened*, and *Hidden* conditions, so it appears that the target of Misty Presence is afflicted by an entirely separate "condition" that isn't covered by their respective rules.

Comment: "Heavily obscured" may be the game term you're looking for to describe the "condition" of the ranger with respect to the creature they are hiding from. Also, are you assuming that the creature has somehow already been made aware of the presence of the ranger, or are they starting from a state of not even knowing about the ranger's presence?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson I don't think heavily obscured fits here because of the issue regarding can't hear them, either. But it seems like they can't be seen or heard...but still felt and smelt.

Comment: @NautArch The flavor text at the beginning of the description is rather vague as well. Depending on your definition of perception, "Remove yourself from one creature's perception" seems to imply that the target would be unable to see or feel the Ranger as well. Seems likely to be errata'd in the final version of the subclass.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The attacker would have Disadvantage, but can target the Ranger.

Assuming the attacker knows the Fey Wanderer Ranger was there at all and tried to attack them, the related rule is in the PHB pages 194-195, emphasis mine:

> When you attack a target that **you can't see**, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. This is true whether you're **guessing the target's location** or you're targeting a creature you can hear but not see.

Obviously the second part about "hear but not see" doesn't apply, but you can still *guess* the target's location.

As stated in [this other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165409/60441) by @SomeRandomOwl, this is different if they have blindsight, or some other way to locate the ranger not based on sight or sound (Maybe they smell really bad).

But since in your case they don't have extra senses, if they have any idea that they are being attacked by a Fey Wanderer Ranger, they could potentially make a completely random attack in a random location and maybe hit them. They're still targeting the ranger, since the only stipulation in the PHB about targeting is picking your target within your attack's range (page 194), but in the wrong area. This would make them automatically miss, with the next sentence of the above quote on page 195:

> If the target isn't in the location you targeted, you automatically miss, but the DM typically just says that the attack missed, not whether you guessed the target's location correctly.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, they are un-targetable

They are un-targetable, based on the wording of the trait:

> The target can repeat the saving throw at the end of any turn during which you hit it with an attack roll, forced it to make a saving throw, or dealt damage to it.

So long as the Fey Wanderer does not attack or or use a spell on the target, it shouldn't be able to target you.

The only way I can think they would be able to see you is if they have blindsight (PHB, p. 183):

> A creature with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight, within a specific radius. Creatures without eyes, such as oozes, and creatures with echolocation or heightened senses, such as bats and true dragons, have this sense.

A creature with blindsight would be able to see you with the wording of Misty Presence, since blindsight isn't reliant on sight or sound.

But since you specified they have normal senses, a normal creature shouldn't be able to perceive you so long as you do not attack them in any way.

Comment: Going to leave this as is but yea what @TheLittlePeace pointed out they would have disadvantage, i forgot about that rule but he is correct. if the target is aware that you exist somewhere nearby they can attempt to hit you even if they don't see or hear you. 

The only exception to that I can think of is if they where unaware of your presence before you made them do the save (i.e suprise round)